# Prevent user from traversing back using browser back button in spring `Web application`

Tags: spring-mvc, browser, back-button

I am developing web application using `spring MVC` frame work, I want to restrict users from traversing back using browsers back  button whenever using my web application. how can I do so in `spring`s? Is there any built in functionality in `spring`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use following filter class in your application, don't forget to register this filter class in web.xml.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class NoBrowserCacheFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)res;
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }

}
```

That's it, it solves your problem.

Comment: I implemented this but this does still does not expire the form when you click the back button.  There is also a local cache.  I have still not found a solution that will expire the form once submitted so that even if you click back, the form should be empty, not cached in any way whatsoever.  Is there any solution to this at all?  This will avoid major double (or even more) submissions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this simple code which will be a false back. 
It would reload the current page and intend to disable the back button on the browser.
this in the intended jsp you want to block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
</script>
```

and add this to the body tag:

```
body onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload=""
```